# Button text appearing outside of button

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, button

I am having a really weird issue here with an HTML button. The text used for the inside of the button is also appearing outside of the button. I am doing a call to both `jQuery` and `jQuery Mobile` in the header with a custom style sheet for the button on the page.

Here is the CSS I am using for the button.

```
button {
color:#000;
font-size:18px;
min-width:150px;
padding:10px;
text-align:center;
text-shadow:1px 1px #FFF;
width:150px;

border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

And here is the code for the button that I am using.

```
<button  onclick="try{ login(); }catch(e){ alert(e); }">Log In</button>
```

And here is what the output actually looks like.

[image]

This is completely blowing my mind. Any suggestions on how I can keep the text from appearing outside of the button?

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/u7DH2/

Comment: You'll need to recreate the error in jsFiddle, as it seems to work just fine for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jFEEz/)

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Also let us know which browser(s) you've tested this in.

Comment: I'm testing in Chrome 24. I'll work on that jsfiddle and post in a sec

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle    http://jsfiddle.net/u7DH2/

Comment: It's something in jQuery 1.7.1 that's doing it.  Remove the script include and it fixes the issue.  As to what it is, I don't know, but unless you specifically need that I'd get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some conflict with jquery-mobile ... if you comment it it fixes the problem.

```
<!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
```

check it here ... jsfiddle.net/u7DH2/2

Comment: The conflict may with jQuery 1.7 then - see my comment above.